# Communication between Heroku apps

Tags: heroku

I've build a distributed system consisting of several web-services and some web applications consuming them.

They are all hosted on Heroku.

Is there some way for request between these applications to be done "inside heroku" without going through the web.

Something analog to using localhost.

Answer (score 3):

You are maybe in luck: such a feature has currently reached the experimental phase.

Let me take a moment to underscore that: this feature may disappear or change at any time.  It's not supported, but bug reports are appreciated.  Don't build a bank with it.  Don't get yourself in a position to be incredibly sad if severe problems are found that render it unshippable and it's aborted.

However, it is still cool, and here it is: [containerized-network](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/containerized-network)

Comment: I'd seen that. But as I understood the documentation this is for communication between processes of the same dyno. I'd like to communicate between applications (different dynos)

Answer (score 1):

You can use, for example, the pub-sub interface of any of the hosted Redis solutions. Or any of the message brokers (IronMQ, RabbitMQ) to pass messages.

Comment: Yep, if by "Internally" you mean "internal to Heroku". They won't go thru the HTTP routing mesh, as requests that come from 'outside' do.

Comment: Depends on the add-on. Some are per-app, some are per-dyno (NewRelic Pro, e.g.), and some are per use of the add-on. Specifically, RedisToGo and RedisCloud have a free option, which might fit your requirements: RedisToGo's free tier is 20MB (iirc) and a few tens of connections, which may fit you if all you're looking for is pub-sub.

Comment: Heroku proposes some add-ons : "RabbitMQ BigWig" or "Cloud AMQP" etc... Sounds great. But there are "cloud solutions", it means that a different company will store and manage that. It's not on the same server. Isn't it ? 
My heroku apps run on "Europe Region" servers, but "RabbitMQ BigWig" runs in USA... When one of my app want to communicate with the other one it will send a message to USA and get back to Europe ? Is it faster than making a REST API between my apps ?!

Comment: Also Postgresql has some pub/sub functionality. If you already share the DB between apps, it's an interesting option.